# Object.freeze doesn't really freeze

Tags: javascript, dom

MDN claims that by executing `.freeze` on an Object:

> Nothing can be added to or removed from the properties set of a frozen object.

Now take a look at this example:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.id = "foo";
console.log(span.id);      //foo

Object.freeze(span);
span.setAttribute("id", "bar");
console.log(span.id);      //bar
```

The `id` property is changed even when the object is frozen. Through `span.hasOwnProperty("id")` we know that `id` is indeed a local property of `span`.

The whole DOM is just an Object in JavaScript so this should prevent `id` from being changed. However it is not doing its thing. Why?

Comment: `setAttribute()` is a method call.  Methods on DOM objects can still change things after freeze.  Freeze affects plain property assignment, not the calling of methods and (according to MDN) not properties that actually have getters and setters behind them.  Plus, `.freeze()` is really design for javascript objects, not DOM objects.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `.id` is still being changed, is because it is not being changed. It only looks like it has changed. `.id` is initially defined with a setter and getter, which grabs the corresponding attribute value upon called. If the preset setter and getter are manually removed, then the value will not change as expected:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
delete span.id;      //remove setter and getter
span.id = "foo";
console.log(span.id);      //foo
Object.freeze(span);
span.setAttribute("id", "bar");
console.log(span.id);      //foo
```

The actual DOM is separate from the accessible object in JS, so `getAttribute("id")` will still return `"bar"`.